# Trigger not working on newly created link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the fasw javascript library - http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/ - to do page transitions in a webapp. It can only appear to be triggered via a data attribute on a link.

```
$('body').prepend('<a class="decider_link_trigger" href="#">[Trigger]</a>');
$('.decider_link_trigger').attr('data-ftrans', 'flip');
$('.decider_link_trigger').attr('href', selected.result);
$('.decider_link_trigger').trigger('click');
```

The above code adds such a link to the page with the provided data-ftrans attribute and is even clickable manually, but I can't figure out how to submit the link with jQuery (or event Javascript).

I cannot do a manual `window.location.href = selected.result;` as this will not use the transition library.

Thanks!

Comment: $('.decider_link_trigger').click();

Comment: `$('.decider_link_trigger')[0].click();`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon even better ;-D

Comment: Tried that too. Didn't work. :(

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon - That works, cheers!